# Can you have client side react and server side react in the same project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project that is likely to grow very large and have multiple teams working on each section.

How can it be possible to have a client-side react "Container" that handles navigation, header and footer? While the main content can be server-side rendered react from different servers so that the teams can deploy features independently?

My first thought was iframes, but we are trying to think outside the box.

Below is a quick picture of what I am trying to do.

[image]

Comment: I'm quite sure this question has already been answered. You're looking for isomorphic code or universal code. There are two repos that I would recommend taking a look at, navigating the sources, and learning from them (or just using them as is to begin your project): [erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) and [kriasoft/react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).

Comment: @rm- I don't think that's what he's asking. They know how to server-render. He's asking how to server-render only part of the app so that the server and client code-bases can be worked on independently.

Comment: So the question is about fetching HTML over asynchronous HTTP request and putting it into some DOM element that is inside the tree a React app controls? The the answer is, 1) fetch as text/html, 2) [dangerously set inner HTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). Or is it something different? Sorry, I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js), setup a custom express server with it and dig into its _app and _document components. You could fetch your remote servers within `getInitialProps`.

To handle some not ssr-rendered content you could wrap them inside `<NoSSR>` tags with [react-no-ssr](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-no-ssr). But in my opinion Nextjs is quite robust and you may get away with it without setting up a whole NoSSR strategy.

If you really need ReactRouter instead of Next.js built-in router (which I love, and I personally extend it with [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) for slugs and named routes) you may use [After.js](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js) which combines Next.js features with RR.

Comment: I second this answer as Next.js is by far the easiest way to do this - and After.js is good second choice if you really like React Router. Although custom routing is easy with Next.js too, and you can easily render content server-only or client-only by detecting where you are running in `getInitialProps` and setting a prop like `isServerSide` to true or false.

Comment: As a follow up in case moderators are reviewing and wondering if question is verging on asking for an opinion, the options boil down to the options above or rolling your own (with or without Create React App), that's about it as there aren't even a bunch of other choices. Rolling your own is not something to approach lightly as maintaining your own client with Universal (client + server) rendering over time while keeping up-to-date with security patches and other updates – including babel and webpack – is non-trivial.

Comment: @IainCollins thanks for this extended information. I expressed it in a quite opinionated way indeed but as you say, it’s basically about not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @IainCollins How does Next.js help with displaying the html is a seperate react application? Without using iframes we could with the dangerously set inner html if the content was just html. This gets complicated because the script tags with a src does not load.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example

This is the cloest you can get. You can render both server side and client side. But if you are asking to do a hybrid of the both, I don't think its possible.